# \addvspace after a titlesec heading

Tags: spacing, sectioning, titlesec

So, I'm trying to make an environment that is always padded above and below by a certain vertical space, no more and no less (unless the previous or following elements require even more space). My attempt is

```
\newenvironment{hello}{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
```

If I then have two `hello` environments one after another, then the second `\addvspace` happily does nothing, as desired. Similarly, after a section title, I get the desired behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{titlesec}
\newenvironment{hello}{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\section{Hellos}
\begin{hello}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{hello}
\begin{hello}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{hello}

\end{document}
```

But when using `titlesec`, there is too much space between the section title and the first `hello` environment. It looks like there's a definite space that goes along with the title that isn't visible to the first `\addvspace` after it, so `\addvspace` adds more space.

Any ideas on how to fix this? (Reasons why my entire approach is crappy are also welcome.)

Comment: It's a small bug in titlesec which uses `\vspace` instead of `\vskip` so it also inserts a `\vskip0pt` which prevents `\addvspace` to work correctly.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet. Not a bug. As the LaTeX Companion explains (p. 858), `\addvspace` is not in fact a user-level command and there are some rather surprissing effects.

Comment: @JavierBezos: I consider it a bug because just loading titlesec changes the behavior of how `\section` are spaced. Is there a reason why you used `\vspace` instead of `\vskip`? The LaTeX kernel never uses `\vspace`.

Comment: @PhilippeGoutet. Of course it changes the behaviour. This is the whole point of titlesec! Using `\vspace` (which, by the way, is used in `\smallskip`, `\smallbreak` and the like), can be more or less sensible and more or less questionable (and the same for `\vskip`, on the other hand), but it's not a bug. And the reason is I though lists after titles were better spaced (again, a questionable decision, but not a bug).

Comment: [I saved a first version too soon and I could not finish the answer.] And the reason is I thought lists after titles were better spaced and it was coherent with `\...skip` (again, a questionable decision, but not a bug).

Comment: @JavierBezos: in what aspects are lists better spaced after sections when using `\vspace`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For its spacing, the package titlesec uses `\vspace` which does not work well with `\addvspace`. You can use the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the internal `\ttl@straight@ii` command in order to replace the `\vspace` by a `\vskip`.

[image: result of the code]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etextools}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\ttl@straight@ii}{\vspace{\@tempskipb}}{\vskip \@tempskipb}{}{}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{hello}{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}

\begin{document}

\section{Hellos}
\begin{hello}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{hello}
\begin{hello}
    \lipsum[3]
\end{hello}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm curious why you said "You can use the *etoolbox* package" in your answer, but then the example uses *etextools* instead (which presumably pulls in etoolbox itself)?

Comment: @dsedivec: a mistake on my part, etoolbox is all that is needed.