# titletoc: \addvspace not working

Tags: titletoc, vspace

Suppose the following simple code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}
    [2em]
    {\addvspace{\baselineskip}}
    {}
    {}
    {}
    [\addvspace{\baselineskip}]  % <----

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A}
\section{B}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using `\addvspace`, I expected that two consecutive `\section`s only add one `\baselineskip` of vertical space between the two entries in the table of contents.
However, this is not the case, which can be seen by commenting out the marked line: the vertical space should not change, but it decreases by half.

How can I solve this?
Is this a bug?

**Edit:** Maybe this is related: [\addvspace after a titlesec heading](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37258/addvspace-after-a-titlesec-heading).

Comment: According to `titletoc` implementation it's not evident that the spaces added with `\addvspace` should merge. Why not use `\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}` and play with spaces in other levels?

Comment: @jlab The problem is that in my more complex project, I want to have different spacings depending on whether there are `\subsection`s or not. For example, I want `\baselineskip` between two `\section`s, `\baselineskip` between `\section` and `\subsection`, but only `.5\baselineskip` between two `\subsection`s. I don't see a way to make this work without some smart mechanism like `\addvspace`

Comment: Maybe play with the starred version `\titlecontents*` which allows more customization, but it's seems more tricky. Another solution is the [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) package, with which you can do almost anything since you format yourself the toc (for example with `enumerate` lists).

Comment: @egreg But this concerns the table of contents; how does this help?

Comment: @egreg Exactly! And my question concerns the table of contents; hence also `titletoc`, not `titlesec`.

Comment: @Gargantuar You're right, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose something with [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) and [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem). [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) provides the toc content through commands like `\etocnumber`, `\etocname` or `\etocpage`. [enumitem](https://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) allows to customize lists, by setting the space before the list (`topsep`), and between items (`\itemsep`).

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\etocsetstyle{section}
    {% before
      \begin{itemize}
         [label={}, topsep=\baselineskip, itemsep=\baselineskip, itemindent=2em]
    }
    {% label
         \bfseries\item%
    }
    {% page
         \etocifnumbered{\makebox[2.25ex][r]{\etocnumber.~}}{}\etocname{}%
         ~\dotfill\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[5.5ex][r]{~\etoclink{p.\hfill\etocpage}}}%
    }
    {% after
      \end{itemize}
    }

\etocsetstyle{subsection}
    {% before
      \begin{itemize}
         [label={}, topsep=\baselineskip, itemsep=0.5\baselineskip, itemindent=2em]
    }
    {% label
         \itshape{}\item%
    }
    {% page
         \etocifnumbered{\makebox[2.25ex][r]{\etocnumber.~}}{}\etocname{}%
         ~\dotfill\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[5.5ex][r]{~\etoclink{p.\hfill\etocpage}}}%
    }
    {% after
      \end{itemize}
    }

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\begin{itemize}
 \item \verb|\baselineskip| between two \verb|\sections|,
 \item \verb|\baselineskip| between \verb|\section| and \verb|\subsection|,
 \item \verb|.5\baselineskip| between two \verb|\subsections|.
\end{itemize}

\section{Section A}

\section{Section B}

\subsection{B1}
\subsection{B2}
\subsection{B3}

\section{Section C}

\section{Section D}

\section{Section E}

\end{document}
```

[image: etoc and enumitem]

Comment: Thanks. Again, everything in LaTeX is solved with lists.